# Can we have some sort of visual feedback to tell us whether or not we've reached the reputation cap for today?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

It's often not immediately obvious whether or not I've reached the reputation cap for today on a site.

- Did I get enough upvotes today?
- I've downvoted something, does it still count?
- I got downvoted, does it still count?

While the information *does* probably exist in the site's FAQ or the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) entries, I propose some sort of visual indication that the rep cap was met. Something like this perhaps?

[image: Rep cap reached]

Comment: Isn't this for a rather narrow audience? :-)  Some people hit the rep cap every day, most people hardly ever.

Comment: Doesn't the check mark, or any mark convey that it's a **goal** to achieve?  That's not really what the rep cap is there for every day.

Comment: I agree with @NickCraver, it should not be a goal. So the indicator should not be a progress bar for example. The indicator you propose seems ok, but only if it is visible once you have reached the limit.

Comment: My question is, what would folks do differently if they had a visual indicator that they hit the cap? Stop answering? That's definitely not something we want to happen :)

Answer (score 9):

I don't think we need that. This is only important if you are here for the points. If you are here to help people, there is no need to take any action if you reached the rep cap.

Besides, you can get your information easy from your activity list and your profile.